# dendrogram in python

Tags: python, dendrogram

I am wanting to write code to draw a dendrogram in python. is there a simple way of going about it.

I have written code that identifies clusters in a point dataset and want to produce a dendrogram that shows the amount of clusters produced for each iteration

for example when i run my code on this dataset i get 1 cluster the first iteration

[image]

and 2 clusters the second iteration

[image]

so i would like to produce something that shows this. but don't really know where to start

[image]

each point has a 'label' attribute which is a list of each cluster the point was in after each iteration.

i.e. in this example some of the points label attribut  is `[0,0]` and the others are `[0,1]`. so if i were to use scipy dendrogram how would i got from this to the linkage format

Answer (score 8):

[SciPy does clustering](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html#module-scipy.cluster.hierarchy) and comes with [a function to turn such clusterings into dendrograms](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram). If you've written your own clustering, perhaps you can still use what SciPy offers?

Comment: i have written my own clustering routine what would i have to input into scipy to produce a dendrogram

Comment: The `dendrogram` function expects input of the same kind as is returned by `linkage`. [The documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage) describes this format.